# Debugging the base URL element with Firebug

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, base-url

I'm adding the [base URL](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/base) tag to the document head using JS, so the relative links on the page work. But it does not take effect, and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (debugging addon for Firefox) shows the `<BASE />` element greyed out.. why? Does this mean Firefox cannot understand it or the syntax is incorrect?

[Image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a3122c1ddd.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a3122c1ddd.png)

Comment: A web page says "The [HTML] code is grayed-out because the element is not visible at the moment" -- http://code.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77412&topic=12044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp

the base tag has two components href and target. Yours seems to be fine. coold you give some example of the links on which it is failing?

see http://ashita.org/StackOverflow/base_test.html for a demonstration. (my test)

Edit: see comments

```
function addBase(url) {
    var regex = /^(https?|ftp):\/\//;

    var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'),0);
    var link = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('link'),0);
    var script = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script'),0);
    var img = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'),0);

    var hrefs = a.concat(link);
    var srcs = img.concat(script);

    var element,href,src;
    for (var i=0,len=hrefs.length;i<len;++i) {
        element = hrefs[i];
        href = element.getAttribute("href");
        if (href) {
            if (!regex.test(href)) {
                href = (url + "/" + href).replace("//","/"); //to handle double slash     collision
                element.setAttribute("href",href);
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i=0,len=srcs.length;i<len;++i) {
        element = srcs[i];
        src = element.getAttribute("src");
        if (src) {
            if (!regex.test(src)) {
                src = (url + "/" + src).replace("//","/"); //to handle double slash     collision
                element.setAttribute("src",src);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested and working in firefox

Comment: Such as this "<link href="templates/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>" ... it looks inside "mysite.com/" instead of "mysite.com/folder/" so it does not find the CSS file.

Comment: firebug still shows the url as relative, but looking at the target url in the status bar, I see the expected address

Comment: Funny how even your base element shows greyout out in my Firebug, I'm adding the base element dynamically with JS, if thats the problem.

Comment: I ran a test on stackoverflow.com and adding the base element via firebug does not grant any benefit. It appears it isn't "scriptable". Looks like you'd have to include it in the original html. (if adding via javascript you could loop through the elements and add it that way, instead of using base)

Comment: "loop through the elements"? In other words?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName(...), loop through every element in the node list, do a regex test on each to check if it includes the protocol in the address, and if not, add your "base" href to the beginning of each one. will edit answer.